# Kivy - inheritance from parent?

Tags: python, kivy

I have a question concerning inheritance of sizes from parents within Kivy.

My program layout so far is something along the lines of:

```
GridLayout (3 cols)
|-------> widget
|-------> widget
|-------> boxlayout (with screenmanager)
             |-----> relative layouts used within each screen
```

I'm having an issue whereby the screenmanager windows all default to size 100, 100 regardless of what I change, and I think it's something to do with the different layouts inheriting from each other, but I am unable to find the source.

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong here, and suggest a fix?

---

**main.py**

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.core.window import Window
from layout import MainLayout

Window.size = (581, 142)

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        self.title = 'Test'
        return MainLayout()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

**layout.py**

```
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from screentest import ScreenTestWidget


class MainLayout(GridLayout):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MainLayout, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        layout = GridLayout(cols=3, col_default_width=200)

        layout.add_widget(Label(text='test'))
        layout.add_widget(Label(text='test'))
        layout.add_widget(ScreenTestWidget())

        self.add_widget(layout)
```

**screentest.py**

```
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen

Builder.load_string("""
<MenuScreen>:
    RelativeLayout:
        Button:
            size_hint: None, None
            size: root.width, root.height * 0.5
            pos: 0, 50
            text: 'Settings'
            on_press:
                root.manager.current = 'settings'
                root.manager.transition.direction = 'down'
        Button:
            size_hint: None, None
            size: root.width, root.height * 0.5
            pos: 0, 0
            text: 'Quit'
            on_press: app.stop()

<SettingsScreen>:
    RelativeLayout:
        Button:
            size_hint: None, None
            size: root.width, root.height * 0.5
            pos: 0, 50
            text: 'Settings'
        Button:
            size_hint: None, None
            size: root.width, root.height * 0.5
            pos: 0, 0
            text: 'Menu'
            on_press:
                root.manager.current = 'menu'
                root.manager.transition.direction = 'up'
""")


class ScreenTestWidget(BoxLayout):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(ScreenTestWidget, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        # Create the screen manager
        sm = ScreenManager()
        sm.add_widget(MenuScreen(name='menu'))
        sm.add_widget(SettingsScreen(name='settings'))
        self.add_widget(sm)


# Declare both screens
class MenuScreen(Screen):
    pass


class SettingsScreen(Screen):
    pass
```

Comment: You'll get `[100, 100]` after you set `size_hint = (None, None)`, so that _might_ be it, but unless there's code, it's harder to tell where's the mistake or a potential bug.

Comment: Well, I do set the `size_hint: (None, None)`, and also `size: root.width, root.height * 0.5`, however the height is never filled? I've tried changing to the `size_hint` to various numbers, however it never reaches the full height of the screen, and I think it's something to do with the GridLayout or the BoxLayout limiting it?

Comment: Can you show us the minimal code to reproduce?

Comment: @syntonym I've updated the question to include a code example. If it works, you can see that the buttons on the screenmanager widget are not reaching the full height of the screen...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you create a MainLayout which inherits from GridLayout. This fills the complete screen. But because you never set columns or rows it never works and will not affect children at all.

Then (in `MainLayout.__init__`) you create a new gridlayout which you add to the MainLayout. MainLayout doesn't work, so `size_hint` does nothing so the GridLayout will default to `size = 100,100`. The position is `pos = 0,0` again by default. This layout has 3 columns and a col_default_width = 200.

To this GridLayout you now add 2 Labels and the ScreenTestWidget. TheGridlayout has now a width of 600. Everything is display as it should

The ScreenTestWidget has `size_hint = 1,1` by default. Thus its size is `size = 200, 100`. Each screen inside also has `size_hint = 1,1` by default, because you never change it. Then each screen has a relativelayout which also has `size_hint = 1,1` by default.

Then the buttons in each screen have custom position and resize with the parent. The parent is the Relativelayout. The Relativelayout resizes with the Screen. The Screen resizes with the ScreenTestWidget. The ScreenTestWidget gets resized by the ColumnLayout. The Columnlayout does *not* resize, because its parent has no cols or rows set and thus doesn't work. Thus it defaults to `100, 100` (but then each child is resized to 200 width).

To fix this you can change the code as following:

```
class MainLayout(GridLayout):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MainLayout, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        # instead of creating a new Layout set the attributes of this one
        self.cols = 3
        self.col_default_width = 200

        self.add_widget(Label(text='test'))
        self.add_widget(Label(text='test'))
        self.add_widget(ScreenTestWidget())
```

Also you don't need the RelativeLayouts in the screens, because Screens are already RelativeLayouts:

```
<SettingsScreen>:
    Button:
        size_hint: None, None
        size: root.width, root.height * 0.5
        pos: 0, 50
        text: 'Settings'
    Button:
        size_hint: None, None
        size: root.width, root.height * 0.5
        pos: 0, 0
        text: 'Menu'
        on_press:
            root.manager.current = 'menu'
            root.manager.transition.direction = 'up'
```

Alternatively you could also set the either rows or cols for the MainLayout.

Comment: Thanks for explaining what is happening in detail! I'm still a bit confused with your first statement though - I thought that the MainLayout is the GridLayout? How would you go about suggesting I fix this? Not sure where to begin...

Comment: The MainLayout is indeed a GridLayout, but it also creates an additional GridLayout in its `__init__` method. If you delete that GridLayout and instead use the MainLayout it should work fine. I added some code to show what I mean.